# What is the systematic way when I want my code (client and server ) work on various scenarios?

Tags: c, linux, cross-platform, 32bit-64bit

I developed in on 64-bit MAC. And I wish it would work under two scenarios:

1. 64 bit server and 64 bit client
2. 32 bit server and 64 bit client

**ONLY DEALING *NIX NOW**

Between the communication of server A and client B, I would exchange a linked list of struct, which is of the following type:

```
typedef struct A{
   unsigned long filed1; 
   int filed2;
   char filed3;
   struct A* next; 
} A_t
```

both size of `char` and `int` are consistent between 32-bit and 64-bit machine. 
My concern is more about the pointer and unsigned long.

My sending/receiving strategy is:

send and receive an array of `list_size * sizeof(A_t)` Bytes, however since the sizeof(A_t) would have different values on 32-bit and 64-bit, my array would have some misalignment. And I wonder what is the most universal way to fix problems of this kind.

Comment: are you asking how to make code portable?

Comment: What do you mean by “pass transport”, and could you finish the last sentence of your question?

Comment: @PascalCuoq just edited, still something not very clear though, will try my best.

Comment: @yuan Your question is clear now, I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq added more details to make it more concrete, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I would say there's no sense in sending memory addresses from server to client as this address points anywhere on the other computer.

Comment: But if you want to send it you could cast them to a 64 bit int

Comment: @scaletos exactly something I want ? To align the array better I may need to make pointers to 64 but size on both32-bit and 64-bit machine I guess ?

Comment: You could replace the pointer by a long and if you then want to use it you have to cast it to a pointer. So on 32 bit machines the high 32 bits are undefined (cause you don't need them)

Comment: but i should add that this is useless after sending the list the elements aren't linked any more because they are at diffrent memaddresses than before

Comment: @scaletos I know sending pointers are useless, just seems eAsier for me to parse it to array in this way and parse array back after receive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should communicate in some universal way that is independent of machine (both word size and endianness). The easiest way is to send as ASCII, for example, as CSV, in the order of the list. The receiver can generate the list back from this.

In principle you should write an IRS, an Interface Requirements Specification, the contract between the two parties. It should deal with order of records, formats and (for example) what the minimum/maximum of numeric fields can be. It is good practice to write this down, how minimal it is and even if the contract is with yourself. Add it to the comment in the relevant functions on the server side and on the client side. Any programmer having to deal with it in the future now knows the constraints of the interface.

Comment: The **quick fix**, though, to my program now, is that I want the `struct A*` have the same **fixed length** on both platforms while keeping syntax right. Meanwhile I change `unsigned long` to `unsigned int` throughout my whole program,  which has the fixed length on both platform. **question:** I don't know how to keep a fixed length of a pointer to struct while maintaining syntax correctness. Any thoughts ?

Comment: The GOOD FIX is to use my proposed method. And you are lucky that both platforms use a processor with the same endianness. Otherwise your ints would all be garbled. And you cannot communicate pointers, so leave the pointer out. Poimters are always dependent on the word length of the platform.

Comment: would protocol buffer be worth trying for avoid endianness ?

Comment: What do you mean by "protocol buffer"?